# Why does this code only work when the input is all capital letters?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

After a good while of research, I've been unable to find why this code counts the capital letters in a sentence when they're all capitalized, but will count `"0"` capital letters if I were to enter a sentence that contains any lowercase letters, such as: `"Hello World"`.

```
message = input("Enter your sentence: ")

print("Capital Letters: ", sum(1 for c in message if message.isupper()))
```

Comment: Probably since your check is `if message.isupper()` did you mean to check: `if c.isupper()` ?

Comment: `sum(map(str.isupper, message))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the condition in your `if` clause is flawed; the `isupper` method returns `True` if *all* characters in the given string are uppercase:

```
>>> "UPPER".isupper()
True
>>> "UPPEr".isupper()
False
```

See the [documentation for `str.isupper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper):

> Return `True` *if all cased characters in `str` are uppercase* and there is at least one cased character in `str`, `False` otherwise.

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

Since you're checking on `message` with `message.isupper(()` this will return `False` all the time resulting in a sum of `0`.

Instead of checking on the full message with `message.isupper()`, use your `if` on a per-character basis with `if c.isupper()` for every `c` in `message`:

```
print("Capital Letters: ", sum(1 for c in message if c.isupper()))
```

You could also take advantage of the fact that `True` acts like `1` and `False` like `0` to slightly trim that down if you'd want:

```
print("Capital Letters: ", sum(c.isupper() for c in message))
```

or, if you like functional approaches, `map` the function to your input:

```
print("Capital Letters: ", sum(map(str.isupper, message)))
```

Even though these might, subjectively, look nicer; they are generally more mystifying than the original approach (and slightly less efficient too).